# Auto expand table range in excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

Tying to find to an Excel VBA  equivalent to

```
sheet.range('A1').expand('table')
#https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html
```

I've tried to create a xlwings func like this :

```
@xw.func
def expand(rng, caller):
    sht = caller.sheet
    return sht.range(rng).expand().address
=expand("C7") returns "$C$7:$E$8" (works)
```

So I've tried for feed this rng as string inside the following macro (that spots changes within a range)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng_s As String
    rng_s = expand("C7") #This is where there is the error
    Set rng = Target.Worksheet.Range(rng_s)
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then my_macro2 (rng)
End Sub
#The Python console returns : TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object
```

Any idea how to make this table expand automatically? Or make this xlwings function work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function directly instead of using xlwings way as they need to correct the code in order to support calling from another function/sub.

Use this in your function instead of calling expand

```
 rng_s = Py.CallUDF("udftest", "expand", Array("C7", Nothing), ThisWorkbook, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C7"))
```

Change `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` for the Sheet where the range you are looking for belongs, that last parameter is passed as the caller in the defined python function, so even you could use only that parameter do get the desired range in your expand function.